# Non deterministic behaviour of socket based application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm working on Client-Server application and I'v hit the wall with one issue. I got `ServerWorker` that is responsible for one connected client, it creates 2 threads, 1 to listen for incoming data from this client and 1 to send data to him.

```
class ServerWorker {
    private DataProcessor dataProcessor;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    private Thread receiverThread;
    private Thread senderThread;
    private Optional<DataPacket> dataToSend;

    private ServerWorker(Socket socket) {
        try {
            dataToSend = Optional.empty();
            dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();
            receiverThread = new Thread(this::readAndProcessData);
            senderThread = new Thread(this::sendData);
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO
        }
    }

    static ServerWorker create(Socket socket) {
        return new ServerWorker(socket);
    }

    void start() {
        receiverThread.start();
        senderThread.start();
    }

    void stop() {
        receiverThread.interrupt();
        senderThread.interrupt();
    }

    private void readAndProcessData() {
        DataPacket dataPacket;
        try {
            while((dataPacket = (DataPacket)inputStream.readObject()) != null) {
                System.out.println("incoming message: " + dataPacket.getContent());
                dataToSend = Optional.of(dataProcessor.process(dataPacket));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            //TODO
        }
    }

    private void sendData() {
        while(true) { //TODO
            dataToSend.ifPresent(data -> {
                try {
                    outputStream.writeObject(data);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    dataToSend = Optional.empty();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //TODO
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And `DataProcessor` is just a small class for now

```
public class DataProcessor {
   public DataPacket process(DataPacket packet){
        packet.setContent(packet.getContent().toUpperCase());
        return packet;
   }
}
```

and ofcourse, `DataPacket` which is the same for both client and server

```
public class DataPacket implements Serializable {
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

`DataProcessor` and `DataPackets` are just kind of POCs now, this will grow into much larger and more complicated classes, long story short, `ServerWorker` will recieve data and pass it to process, then after some logic is done, returning data will be stored inside `dataToSend` variable and removed after sending. Problem is, code I'v posted above works only sometimes. 90% of the time when I run my server app and client one (code below) nothing happens, uppercased "hello world" isnt going back to client. What's funny, when I run my server in debug mode (even without any breakpoints!), it works... Any ideas what the heck went wrong?

```
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        DataPacket dataPacket = new DataPacket();
        dataPacket.setContent("hello world");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        os.writeObject(dataPacket);
        os.flush();

        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while((dataPacket = (DataPacket)inputStream.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println(dataPacket.getContent());
        }
    }
```

edit#
adding one more class, `ConnectionDispatcher` that is responsible for creating `ServerWorker` objects

```
class ConnectionDispatcher implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<ServerWorker> serverWorkers;
    private volatile boolean isReceiving;

    private ConnectionDispatcher(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
        isReceiving = false;
    }

    static ConnectionDispatcher create(int port) throws IOException {
       return new ConnectionDispatcher(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isReceiving = true;
        while(isReceiving) {
           acceptIncomingConnections();
        }
    }

    private void acceptIncomingConnections() {
        try {
            ServerWorker worker = ServerWorker.create(serverSocket.accept());
            serverWorkers.add(worker);
            worker.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're modifying `dataToSend` from one thread while simultaneously reading its value in another. This isn't thread-safe, and the thread that's reading its value may never see its updated value set by the other thread. For this reason, I'd declare `dataToSend` as `volatile`.

```
private volatile Optional<DataPacket> dataToSend;
```

I have not yet had the chance to test this out myself, but I can in about an hour (assuming this change doesn't fix your problem).

Answer (score 1):

You could uses a Array Blocking Queue, to simulate a producer and consumer pattern.

Let the receiver thread, put new DataPacket into the queue, and let the sender take from the queue and process it and send it.

This will eliminate threading issues and acts as a buffer.

With your current code, you might loose packets,when they arrive at higher rate.

And i agree with user930,  `private Optional<DataPacket> dataToSend;` should be volatile.

Also you can make your code much scalable with JavaNIO, you could look into [Apache Mina](https://mina.apache.org/) project.